# How to capture backspace?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check for the “backspace” character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363309/how-to-check-for-the-backspace-character-in-c)

I just want to copy its input to its
output, replacing each tab by `\t`, each
backspace by `\b`, and each backslash by
`\\`. However, i use the similar method
like replacing each tab by `\t` cannot
replacing each backspace by `\b`.How can
I capture backspace?

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    main(){
      int c;


      char tab='t';
      char bsps='b';

      int i;
      int j;
      while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
      { 

        if(c == 9)
        { 
            putchar(92);
            putchar(tab);

        } 
        else if(c == 8)
        { 
            putchar(92);
            putchar(bsps);
        } 
        else if(c == 92)
        { 
             putchar(92);
                 putchar(92);
        } 
        else putchar(c);
      }

    }
```

Comment: I guess you were working on the question 1-10 of  c programming language. You can use (ctrl + h) to input 'backspace', as wikipedia suggests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#.5EH

Answer (score 1):

Your program is correct. The problem is that it never sees the backspace character which is "eaten" be the line editing method of your OS.

You type <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Basckspace</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but your program only gets <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

I compiled your program and tested it with my OS.

First a simple test

```
$ echo -e 'a\bc' | wc
      1       1       4
```

This shows 1 newline, 1 word, and 4 bytes.

Then a run of the program

```
$ echo -e 'a\bc' | ./a.out 
a\bc
```