# How come \b is not recognized from ex. 1-10 in K&R?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* replace tabs and backspaces with visible characters */

main()

{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\t')
            printf("\\t");
        if (c == '\b')
            printf("\\b");
        if (c == '\\')
            printf("\\\\");
        if (c != '\b')
            if (c != '\t')
                if (c != '\\')
                    putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Why was I not able to see \b backspace signature when I press the backspace?

Comment: a couple of comments on your code: `getchar` is evil, conditions with side-effets are evil, and if cascades are evil as well (if they can be conveniently replaced by switch/case statements, which is the `case` here. :D (pun intended)

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Backspace` = `^H`

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about `else`, that if-ladder is pretty scary.

And your terminal probably doesn't send a single backspace character, it can be [a bit complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#.5EH) how actual terminal programs represent that kind of "special" key (delete is another favorite).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a unix-like system, you probably want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooked_mode

On other operating systems, I don't know, but they are also likely to do things to your input.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the characters handled by `Terminal`. So you can't get control over it. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363309/how-to-check-for-the-backspace-character-in-c#answer-4363345).

I tried in my `MAC` terminal. But i didn't get the value `127` or `8` like, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363309/how-to-check-for-the-backspace-character-in-c#answer-4363345). I got `32` for `backspace` character. So when i tried the `if` condition with `32`, it printed out the `\b` value.

```
if (c == 32 || c == 8)
    printf("\\b");
```