# Not being able to get backspace character (\b) in the output

Tags: c, windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
        }
        if (c == '\b') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
        }
        if (c == '\\') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
        }
        if (c != '\t')
            if (c != '\b')
                if (c != '\t')
                    putchar(c);
    }
}
```

My question is - why can't i see the `\b` output? I'm currently learning K&R C and using Windows 10. I can't get a `\b` symbol in the Windows command line, while on Ubuntu it works pretty much ok. I've tried CTRL + H, but still no `\b`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why do you desperately want to input a backspace?

Comment: Very likely your application doesn't get the backspace, as the console program is handling it itself.

Comment: On another (and unrelated) note, your code could be cleaner with a `switch` statement, where last nested `if` would be the `default` case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Doesn’t even need to be a `switch`, a simple `else if` would suffice.

Comment: How are you launching the application? In particular, how are you feeding it input, and what’s the input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check for the "backspace" character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363309/how-to-check-for-the-backspace-character-in-c)

Comment: If you want to get unprocessed keyboard input you could use function `getch` from `ncurses` or (non-portable, DOS/Windows only) `getch`/`_getch` from `conio.h` See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028974/10622916